# Sort by property on nested list c#

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a list I would like to sort by a property inside of a nested list.  If the property value exists inside of one of the objects, I'd like it to be first in the list. Otherwise if the property does not exist, to sort it by a property in the parent object.

Code:

Here's the top level class;

I'd like to sort by a specific **TagId**.  Then by **NoteId** in ascending order.

```
  public class NoteDto
{
    string NoteText { get; set; }

    public int NoteId { get; set; }

    public List<TagDto> Tags { get; set; }

}
```

Nested object class:

```
 public class TagDto
 {
    public int TagId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

  }
```

Example : If the **TagId** is 22, I'd like it to be first in the list, otherwise sort by **NoteId** in Ascending Order.

**Before Sort**

```
NoteText: "TestNote1",
NoteId: 1,
Tags: { TagId: 13, Name: "TestTag1" }, { TagId: 16, Name: "TestTag5" } 

NoteText: "TestNote2",
NoteId: 2,
Tags: { TagId: 14, Name: "TestTag2" }, { TagId: 17, Name: "TestTag6" }  

NoteText: "TestNote3",
NoteId: 3,
Tags: { TagId: 15, Name: "TestTag3" }, { TagId: 18, Name: "TestTag7" }

NoteText: "TestNote4",
NoteId: 4,
Tags: { TagId: 22, Name: "TestTag4" }, { TagId: 19, Name: "TestTag8" }
```

**After sort:**

```
NoteText: "TestNote4",
NoteId: 4,
Tags: { TagId: 22, Name: "TestTag4" }, { TagId: 19, Name: "TestTag8" } 

NoteText: "TestNote1",
NoteId: 1,
Tags: { TagId: 13, Name: "TestTag1" }, { TagId: 16, Name: "TestTag5" } 

NoteText: "TestNote2",
NoteId: 2,
Tags: { TagId: 14, Name: "TestTag2" }, { TagId: 17, Name: "TestTag6" }  

NoteText: "TestNote3",
NoteId: 3,
Tags: { TagId: 15, Name: "TestTag3" }, { TagId: 18, Name: "TestTag7" }
```

Comment: Can you show us your attempts?

Comment: `"If the TagId is 22, I'd like it to be first in the list, otherwise sort by NoteId in Ascending Order."` -- This does not make a whole lot of sense, specifically the "otherwise" part.  If the `TagId` is _not_ exactly 22 you want to sort by `NoteId`?

Comment: I am confused on your example because tagid 22, goes first and then you go to tagid 13. I do not get the logic..

Comment: This isn't a sort question if you want to arbitrarily place Tag 22 on the top. You should sort by Note ID and then just insert Tag 22 at the beginning of the sorted list.

Comment: @maccettura Yes if the TagId is not 22 then to sort by the noteId.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this

```
var sorted = notes.OrderByDescending(note => note.Tags.Any(t => t.TagId == 22))
                     .ThenBy(note => note.noteId);
```

An order was init to put firstly the notes with tag = 22, then, order by noteId